# How to randomly assign elements from a list to coordinates?

Tags: python

```
Sumlist = ['9', '2', '7', '1', '5', '3', '4', '6', '8', '$', '$', '$', '$', '$', 'K', 'I', 'Q', 'J', 'T', 'V', 'D', 'B', 'R', 'Y', 'L', 'Z', 'U', 'P', 'A', 'W', 'C', 'O', 'G', 'M', 'H', 'S', 'N', 'E', 'X', 'F']
```

And let's say given some coordinates such as:

```
gridxy = [1,2] [1,3] [1,4] [2,2] [2,3] [2,4]
```

Now my question comes: How does i randomly assign the elements in my Sumlist to each of my coordinates through python? Do i use if and else statement?

I don't think I will be using tuples in this one.

Comment: Your gridxy coordinates uses just numbers from SumList?

Comment: dont you think that its better at least pass a bit  of the way by your self ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "assign to". Do you mean that you wish to create a dictionary where you can look up by coordinates and find the sumlist value? If so, then your coordinates will have to be made tuples, because lists can't be dictionary keys. Or maybe they are coordinates of a 2D list-of-lists?

Comment: gridx is not valid Python, could you please define better the data structures that you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`random`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) module to randomly [`sample`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) your Sumlist and associate each element to the element in gridxy using the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) builtin function :

```
Tested on Python 2.7.9

>>> import random
>>> Sumlist = ['9', '2', '7', '1', '5', '3', '4', '6', '8', '$', '$', '$', '$', '$', 'K', 'I', 'Q', 'J', 'T', 'V', 'D', 'B', 'R', 'Y', 'L', 'Z', 'U', 'P', 'A', 'W', 'C', 'O', 'G', 'M', 'H', 'S', 'N', 'E', 'X', 'F']
>>> gridxy = [[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,2],[2,3],[2,4]]
>>> random.seed()
>>> zip(gridxy, random.sample(Sumlist, len(gridxy)))
[([1, 2], '$'), ([1, 3], '1'), ([1, 4], '6'), ([2, 2], 'X'), ([2, 3], '$'), ([2, 4], '$')]
```